# Add iOS mobile favicon images to magento Shop

Tags: html, ios, iphone, favicon, magento-1.9

I just created a favicon icon set with realfavicongenerator and now want to implement the code for the mobile devices to my site.

On which page should I add this to the header section? Just the home CMS page of my Magento store?

Answer (score 0):

you should add your code in  YOUR_THEME/iphone/template/page/html/head.phtml

Add something like this

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('touch_icon.png') ?>"/>
```

More info [here](http://astrio.net/blog/magento-mobile-touch-icon/).

Comment: i can find this path:

`/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/page/html`

but i dont use the magento default theme. so do i need to add `/iphone/template/page/html` to my theme which is in use?

Comment: Yes you need to add the file in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done through XML instead of directly in the template as taschert recommended:

```
<action method="addLinkRel">
    <rel>apple-touch-icon</rel>
    <href>/path/to/the/icon.png</href>
</action>
```

For example in your `local.xml` file of your custom theme.